Best practice for unique constraint: multiple columns VS generated column
I have several tables in which "whole" items are stored across multiple columns for each of their "parts," and I wish to ensure that the "whole" is unique. These tables each contain a generated column that return the "whole" in its proper format.
For example, I have an "addresses" table with columns "address_id, line1, line2, city, state, ZIP, ZIP4" and the generated column "full_address" as
CONCAT(line1, CHAR(10 using utf), IFNULL(line2, '', CONCAT(line2, CHAR(10 using utf))), city, ', ', state, IFNULL(zip4, zip, CONCAT_WS('-', zip, zip4)))
My question is: is it better to use a multi-column unique constraint across line1, line2, city, state and ZIP or a single-column unique constraint on full_address? What differences/tradeoffs occur under the hood? Are the differences proportional to the number of columns being combined?

An index on all the columns has the added benefit of being useful in some queries that select based on those columns.

it is very unclear what you mean by whole? and multiple tables, please add all relevant tables as CREATE TABLe

Will you be using this generated column for anything other than this unique constraint? If not, it's probably causing unnecessary overhead to calculate the generated column.

@Barmar Yes, the generated column is there because it is most often the desired result of the query. (The user searches by ID and usually wants to read the complete, formatted address; the constituent columns are really only needed for create/update.)

If it's a stored column, then indexing it is probably simplest.

If you create an index by this generated column then the column itself may be virtual which will save both disk space and server resources (the expression value may be extracted from the index).

A unique constraint on multiple nullable columns may not do what you intend, because if any column is null, the row doesn't count as a duplicate. Whereas making a unique constraint on the virtual column you show does enforce uniqueness, since it converts nulls to non-null empty strings.

Your whole column is functionally dependent on other columns, so it is a composite of values and it is good that you think about two alternatives. But since your whole column violates 1NF, it makes more sense to create a multidimensional index on the fields that defines it, because then searching them will be quicker, but you do not need to always index by an actual field, you can index by expressions too.
Think of the whole column as a function, because it is effectively one and how much composite indexes will help you in doing partial searches, like searching by line1 and line2, for example.
Indexing by the whole field is the simplest, so you may start with that one. After all you can destroy an index and create new indexes whenever you wish.
